# VBA Nesting countif inside of If statement

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA I have a countifs formula that returns a number depending on the value cell F3. F3 is a data validation. I am able to pick individual cases out with my formula, but I am having trouble making an "all" values selection. Researching I came up with "*" as my value to pull everything (the wildcard). Conditional formatting wont let me mask the name as something else due to it being a star. Any ideas on how to display the name as something else, or changing my formula to pull all names in column AF? Thank you very much! Matt.

```
Sheets("Macro").Range("M54") = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("E5:E" & finRow), _
         "=Addition", .Range("N5:N" & finRow), _
         "=" & Sheets("Macro").Range("$D$3").Value, .Range("AF5:AF" & finRow), _
         "=" & Sheets("Macro").Range("$F$3").Value)
```

Comment: Is the issue with the formula or is the issue with how you're conditionally formatting?

Comment: I can't conditional format with a *. I'm hoping someone might know of another way to display different text than the value in the same cell. If not, I am hoping for a suggestion on how to reformate the formula to allow me to select individual words or all words in column AF depending on what I type into the data validation spot. Thank you for the reply

Comment: The last part of your countif is not needed when dealing with F3, so you might want 2 countifs and have an if-statement or some switch to decide WHICH countif you want, be if the one that looks in columns E, N, and D, or the one that wants E, N, D, and AF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your issue correctly (which is that your data validation list in cell F3 is currently working properly with your VBA code, but you're looking for a way to display the asterisk as another word like "All"), then I would suggest changing your data validation list from displaying the asterisk to displaying "ALL" and editing your VBA to accommodate that change.  For example:

```
If Sheets("Macro").Range("F3").Value = "ALL" Then

Sheets("Macro").Range("M54") = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("E5:E" & finRow), _
         "=Addition", .Range("N5:N" & finRow), _
         "=" & Sheets("Macro").Range("$D$3").Value, .Range("AF5:AF" & finRow), _
         "=*")
Else

Sheets("Macro").Range("M54") = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("E5:E" & finRow), _
         "=Addition", .Range("N5:N" & finRow), _
         "=" & Sheets("Macro").Range("$D$3").Value, .Range("AF5:AF" & finRow), _
         "=" & Sheets("Macro").Range("$F$3").Value)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. The coding worked great! Still trying to learn.